# How to find all the variables used in another expression variables directly or indirectly in Java

Tags: java, algorithm, pattern-matching

If I have some variables with expressions like below. And I want to determine programatically which of the variable expressions are being referred directly or indirectly. How do I approach this recursive problem ?

V1 = 1;

V2 = V1 + 6 * 5;

V3 = V2 + V4

V4 = 5 + V5

V5 = 6

Here V2 is directly dependent on V1 and V3 is indirectly dependent on V1 , V4 , V5 are not dependent on V1 directly/indirectly.

Comment: You can't do it using pattern matching.  However, you need to provide more context if you want a useful answer.  Is this Java code?  Expressions in some other language?  Are they represented as text, or some parsed form?  Details please.

Comment: I think our example is wrong.. V2 depends on V1... but V3 depends on V2 and V4 and indirectly depends on V1 and V5...  and V5 doesn't depend on V1... is that what you are saying?

Comment: @Stephen This is a java program. For each variable expression I have already parsed the expression and have a structure to store dependent variables.

Comment: @Charles What I mean is V4 , V5 can be calculated without knowing the value of V1 , So V4 is not dependent on V1. Where as to calculate V2 , V1 must be known and V1 is directly used in expression. V3 cant be calculated without calculating V2  and V4 ; V4 can be calculated without V1 but V2 cant so , V3 is indirectly dependent on V1 due to V2 having dependency on V1.

Comment: See [`dependency graph algorithm`](https://www.google.com/search?q=dependency+graph+algorithm)

Answer (score 3):

I would store all that information in a

```
HashMap<Variable dependent,List<Variable dependee>>
```

The first level get in the map will return everything you are directly dependent on.  Recursively calling the table with the results variables you are directly dependent on will give you the indirect relationships.  When traversing the tree watch out for cycles.

Comment: It's good to point out that this is an adjacency list representation for a graph.